# WPF, WindowFormsHost, memory

Tags: c#

I writing my app with WPF 4.

Basically it occupy about 25 Mb (value from taskbar).
Then I add a WindowsFormsHost with windows forms control. So the memory is up to 100 Mb. And then it becomes 60 Mb (5 - 10 seconds ago).

WindowsFormsHost located in Grid, and using GridSplitter, also leads to memory leap.

Does this behavior is ordinary for WPF?

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET runtime itself consumes some amount of memory and I don't know that your measurements are accurate enough to say definitively that the `WindowsFormsHost` object is causing the jump.  Every non-trivial .NET app I write, be it WinForms or WPF, consumes about 60-100 MB at startup, sitting there doing nothing.  Is this amount of memory usage a probelm for you?  If it is than I suggest using a different technology that gives you more determinism, but I doubt that it really is an issue.

If you're really concerned about it run your app through a profiler and see what memory is going where.  I have had good experiences with the [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/). I don't work there, just a happy customer =).   They have a 14 day free trial.